# Power Bi Report Builder - Add dynamic image on Paginated Report

Tags: pagination, powerbi

I have a paginated report and I want to be able to embed image dynamically on the report. How do I do that.

**Here is the use case:**

I want a functionality that  will give a capability to choose an image and embed on the report. The image is basically a signature, user should be able to select the signature based on their need.

Note: Signature is not related to data, it will be driven by report user.
Note: I am using Power Bi Report Builder tool

Comment: Can you host the image somewhere? It's possible to have the URL of the image saved on a column and then load the image from the URL dynamically.

Comment: @JoaoLeal  I have host the image in a database or in Power Bi itself. Can you suggest?

Comment: It needs to be in a public location, for example a public list in SharePoint, or public One Drive or even imgur